# Custom ring shape Circular progress view with dashed block

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, geometry

I need to create a ring shape progress bar with black strip as something like attached image ,As Progress increase the red color fill with sky color .When progress reach to the half of circle than it start to draw yellow color and sky color remain filled.

How can i achieve this view ?which approach should i use for this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

see this demo to help you to create dashed circular progressbar [Click Here](https://github.com/glomadrian/dashed-circular-progress)

and you can make custom progress bar using this demo.